# JForm display in admin side

Tags: joomla, jform

I am working in Joomla. I have install the JForm component that create form and display in front end.
Now i want to display created form at administrator side.
   So anybody know how to display created form in administrator side.....

Answer (score 0):

A form on the administrator side is not as simple as just adding a form because the form would have to be connected to a database table of some sort. A form on the admin side is really a component. You can either create an entire component on your own or you can use ChromoForms and ChronoConnectivity to create the same effect. Neither way is particularly simple unless you are pretty familiar with Joomla and PHP.

Build a component - http://docs.joomla.org/Developing_a_Model-View-Controller_Component_-_Part_1

ChronoForms and ChronoConnetivity - http://www.chronoengine.com/

Comment: Hello Brent, there is free ChronoForms component available for joomla 1.5 if have please give me a link for download. I install but its not working because of shareware.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response, I missed your comment. You should be able to get the complete extensions here - http://www.chronoengine.com/downloads.html

Comment: FYI - the license only removes the ChronoEngine branding, it does not disable any features.